# Programmatically login to Apple iCloud and Find My Network

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, icloud, webrequest

I try to programmatically connect to the find-my network (belonging to iCloud) to locate devices attached to my Apple-ID.

This should pe possible using web requests. For example I post a request with my credentials to:

https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/login

```
string jsonreq = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);  //temp is an object with login credentials

byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonreq);
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/login");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers.Set("Origin", "https://www.icloud.com");
webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Attach the data.
newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
// read server url, dsid, Cookie from response
```

This is working in the first step, but now I'm facing the problem that 2 factor authentication is to be used for logging in.

Can someone help me/show me next steps in the login process via web request for 2 factor authentication? (Of course I receive the login authentication code on my apple devices)

Comment: Use NetworkCredential.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0

Comment: Using NetworkCredentials is not working for me. A login will lead to http status code 400 (wrong request) ... by the way, this would not be a solution for my problem with 2 factor authentication.

Comment: See following : https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Implementing-Sign-In-with-Apple-in-ASPNET-Core.  Not all servers allow 2 factor authentication.

Comment: Thx for your reply but this link is not leading to a solution of my problem. It describes how to use apple sign in with third party web sites. But this is not my question. I want to login to apple (iCloud, Find my) directly... not to a third party ... by using web requests.

Comment: The title of the link is sign in with ASP.Net.  Why would it be any different that your Net application?  The code is using an HttpRequest.

Comment: Yes, but the link is describing how to sign in WITH apple sign in ... not TO apple. We would like to sign/log in to apple iCloud programmatically, not to third party platforms by using "Apple sign in". ("Apple sign in" seems to be related to other forms of signing in like "Google sign in" or "Facebook sign in")

Comment: I only see Net methods which create a Apple compatible key for signing.